# Creature animation

Tags: ios, animation, 2d

I am looking into making an iOS app that has little creatures. I plan on having these creatures grow and change shapes based on user interaction. So the creatures could end up looking very different based off what the user does.

My problem is animating these creatures. I have dealt with simple animations in the past with cocos2d, but nothing like this.

How can I animate these creatures being different sizes and shapes without having my graphic designer draw every possible image that could be used. In the game spore a user can create an animal of whatever shape or size they want and these animals animate. My question is how can I do something similar in 2d? I know this can't be a simple answer, but a point in the right direction is all I am looking for.

Comment: there is no simple answer. if you want to animate them, you have to animate them! Probably best done on a 2d animation software and then exported as sprite sheets to be used with Cocoa.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think the Spore creatures might use some simple 3d rendering and some mesh deformation algorithms. Either that or they were very clever with graphics and animations.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some `CGAffineTransforms` to scale your drawing and custom filters with Core Image maybe to change the color.

Comment: Don't use these with cocos2d. Use actions (CCMoveTo/By, CCScaleTo/By, CCRotateTo/By, etc). I don't know which method is better performance-wise, but you will have far less stupid errors when you use actions. :)